# Geektool Ruby script fails to load gems

Tags: ruby, shell, rubygems, geektool

I'm trying to use Ruby to write a couple scripts for geektool. However, I've found that geektool can't process

```
require "some_gem"
```

Where does geektool execute shell commands? Is it possible to make gems available to to it there, or force the scripts to run in the normal shell environment? Someone attempted to answer this question [here][1].

```
    /Users/Dave/.rvm/bin/rvm use 1.9.3-p0 > /dev/null
    /Users/Dave/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby ~/foo.rb
```

However, this fails with RVM throwing an error, that it is not an application, and that I must enable login.

I'd really appreciate some help on getting Ruby gems to work in geektool

Comment: Where did they try to answer it?

Comment: My bad, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528536/how-to-run-ruby-scripts-in-geektool

Comment: you could try a `require "rubygems"` before it?

Comment: `require 'rubygems'` isn't needed with Ruby versions > 1.9. It's automatically done.

Comment: yea it didn't help me, interestingly the geektool passed `require "rubygems"` but froze at `require "stock_quote"`. Not sure if that helps at all. Also, I've seen something like `#!/usr/bin/env ruby` posted at the top of some scripts, how does this affect the behavior of the script?